# HOW TO KEEP A CONNECTION WITH SOCKETS

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection

I need to do a Socket serv (gateway) to receive data packages from a car tracker (JIMI VL02).

The problem is: **i dont know how to keep the conection with the tracker.**

The oldest serv that i made (for other type of car tracker) was quit the connection after receive a package, like the example below.

```
localip = ''
port = 5005
bufferSize = 1024
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server.bind((localip, port))
server.listen()

while True:
    client, adress = server.accept()  
    main(client, adress) 

def main():
  .
  .
  .
 client.close()
```

In the function main i made the whole necessary process with the package and after that the code close the conection to receive a new package from other or the same tracker.

This type of server (socket) works if the tracker send your ID in every each package, but now the new type of tracker (JIMI VL02) just send the ID in the first package (login package) and if i close the conection he send again the login package.

**So how can i keep the conection with the tracker?** i don't know much about sockets. If anyone knows the name of the type of sockets i need it will help a lot already

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. There's so much implied context that your question is missing. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  is better know ?

Comment: "if i close the conection..." -- then don't close the connection? Please also try to go through any random Python socket tutorial, they should include examples (often a chat application) that demonstrate how to use sockets.